# Removing support for Lenovo's Battery Safeguard "feature"

Tags: windows, battery, lenovo-laptop

Lenovo laptops [now include](http://forum.notebookreview.com/lenovo/668357-battery-safeguard-comes-t-series.html) a Battery Safeguard "feature" that disallows use of third-party batteries in models made after May 2012 or so.

It appears this "feature" is provided by a Windows driver as a particular Lenovo laptop in question will:

- stay powered in Windows on AC
- stay powered in Windows on the original battery
- **shut down instantly** in Windows on the replacement third-party battery
- stay powered in Linux on AC
- stay powered in Linux on the original battery
- stay powered in Linux on the replacement third-party battery

It's interesting to note that if running on the third-party battery, Windows only shuts down after logging in and the user utilities have loaded. Which makes me think it's a driver or userspace application implementing this "feature", not hardware.

What driver or program do I need to disable to remove support for Battery Safeguard?

Comment: Wow; really classy Lenovo. I suspect this has less to do with actualy safety than profit-protection. ¬_¬ Anyway, you can check what programs, services, and drivers are running on your system with [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx). You can hide the standard Microsoft ones to reduce clutter, then look for anything with `len` or `bat` or `pow`, then disable it, reboot, and see if it works. It’s more time-consuming, but it’s best to do one at a time to be sure you get the right one.

Comment: The non-installation of Lenovo's battery software should prevent the driver from being installed.

Comment: Reinstall Windows (from ISO>flash), or uninstall driver. What's the problem?

Comment: @Synetech - or the installation of Hoverboard batteries. I'd go for the "we're selling them in the US and don't want to get embroiled in Lithium Flamer lawsuits because the third party battery was a dud".