# Is there an Acer battery management tool that limits the battery charge? Should I even bother?

Tags: laptop, battery, acer-aspire

I have a personal laptop (Lenovo Z470) at home and what I like about it is that its battery management software has a setting called "Best Battery Health" which makes the laptop stop charging at 50% battery capacity. It's useful because I used my laptop 8+ hours a day, everyday. Although I total discharge it about once a month.

Now I have a new job and a new laptop was provided me, an Acer Aspire E1-572G. Its battery tool doesn't have that feature, and googling didn't come up with any results.

So do you guys know any software that does the same thing on Acer notebooks? Or if it's not the best practice (to keep the battery at a certain level), what is? I'm asking because I'll be using this laptop the whole day. Any recommendations? Thank you.

PS: I noticed on my Lenovo notebook, when I set it to Best Battery Health then reboot to Ubuntu, the battery threshold remains, so I'm thinking it's not totally a software thing. It may be hardware-related, too, but I don't know. Thanks again.

Comment: You would think that in this day and age, this functionality would be built into the battery circuitry so that we don’t have to worry or even think about it. If they can make it so that a laptop [only works with their own batteries](http://superuser.com/questions/697737/), surely they can make the battery take care of itself.

Comment: While Lithium based batteries should be cycled fully the first two or three times they're used (i.e. fully discharging the battery, then fully recharging it), Lithium based batteries do not have a "memory" like NiCad batteries.  All lithium based batteries have a limited lifespan due to the physics of how a battery works, however semi-heavy users should get at least 1 - 2 years out of their batteries in peak performance and likely an additional year or so with a noticeable decrease in time before the battery is discharged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short answer:* **No and no**

*Long answer:*

I was skeptical of this affirmation so I did some research and stumbled with [this](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries) article. And it brought back vague memories from back when I studied physics about condensers.

Now before we start, I want to point out that to my understanding, saying battery is fully charged makes just as much sense as saying a balloon is fully charged; this limit is too extreme since it's where it's the limit where it explodes. So the battery is never **fully** charged.

Give this graph I found a look: It's very descriptive.
[image: voltagetimecapacitor]

When connecting the battery to a specific voltage by using your charger, the charge behaves as you can see in the graph over time. It charges the battery quick first and then slower until it reaches a point it will charge so slow we don't consider it charging anymore. This is probably the moment your laptop says battery 100%.

If you charged the battery using a higher voltage, you'd raise this limit, the battery would charge faster and it would have a longer discharge duration at the expense of making the battery "suffer" and hence reduce its life. Too much voltage and KABOOM BABY!

On the other hand, if you use a lower voltage to charge the battery, it would take the same time to charge it to... let's say 50% of last scenario (and it would be limited there), so you'd have less juice through the day but the life of the battery would be prolonged. I bet your laptop would also state the battery is at 100%, even though it now has half the charge as before.

You could also "fast charge" it to that 50% using that higher voltage, but that's going to make the battery "suffer" as well.
Back to the first article, I found there this other graph as well:
[image: voltagecharges]

So in **conclusion**, you shouldn't focus on charging your battery less to improve its life, but to charge it **slower by reducing the voltage** (which will put a limit to how charged it gets hence charging it less).

But on the other hand all new batteries probably have internal mechanisms which regulate all of this so you don't even need to think about it.

Oh, and about programs to limit this; it MUST be supported by acer from the BIOS. If it isn't around, then it's probably just not supported.

Comment: Woah, this question made me learn a lot about batteries by doing some research, and now I understand why the hell they designed my external phone battery charger to charge so extremely slow (takes about a full day) using less voltage than an USB. I'm now wondering if computer circuitry works with a varying voltage...

Comment: I understand. But how do I lower the voltage of my charger? And also, is it safe to leave the laptop plugged in even if it says 100% on the battery level?

Comment: It's okay to leave it plugged, it disconnects itself when 100%. As for lowering the voltage of the charger you could use a different charger if it fits. Now then, you also have to check the current it provides so it's enough but doesn't fry your computer. On the other hand I don't know that much about electricity and I discourage you to do it...

Comment: From what I've read around the internet, it's fine as long as the amperage is higher or equal to your old charger. Even with numbers like using 4A when before you used 1.9A. Be also careful with the polarity of the connector, it must match.

Comment: Okay then. I'll leave it plugged in the whole day. Hey, I've learned a lot from you answers, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/software-acer-care-center

download the acer care center, Head to TUNE UP >> then CHECK UP (on the left) >  BATTERY > Go to Tab 2 > ON[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJT6J.png)

Answer (score 1):

Many users do not use their notebooks too often on the go, and they are plugged to AC nearly all the time, keeping the battery charged at 100%. This is the worst mode of operation for ANY lithium-based battery.

My friend's HP Probook 4535s has a Windows utility which allows to specify the charge limit to 50%, 70% or 100%. They say 50% is for maximum battery lifespan, 100% is highest single-charge run time and 70% is good compromise. I wish there would be such a possibility for Acer Aspire.

For now, I normally let the battery charge to about 50% (which is an ideal state of charge for Li-based batteries) and remove it from the laptop. When needed, I just put it there and it charges to 100% in about an hour, which is acceptable in most cases. And when not, I still have those 2 hours at 50% which is sufficient for most of my on-the-go activities.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lenovo that is not capable of controlling charge level to other than 100%. (I understand that the Thinkpad line can do this but I have an Ideapad.)

I use a WiFi programmable socket which can be operated by software on the laptop. I have a script that runs every 5 minutes and when the battery charge is over 70% it turns the socket off. When battery charge is below 30% it turns the socket back on. (Charger plugged into socket, of course.) After several years the battery capacity on this laptop is holding up better than previous laptops which were allowed to charge to 100% and left on charge nearly indefinitely.

Comment: Fully charging a lithium based battery does not degrade it's lifespan... There could be a myriad of reasons as to why you're experiencing perceived better performance over that of previous hardware.  The quality of the battery and it's electrolyte formulation, the battery circuitry [PCB controller], the power circuitry of the motherboard, the drivers and/or software written by the OEM, the OS, etc.  For example, Windows 10 has a feature that will turn the charger off once the battery is charged.  Other contributing factors are discharge cycles, climate used in, & quality of hardware components

Comment: I very seldom use my laptops not plugged in. Every one I have owned has experienced battery deterioration often to the point where the system would not operate when not plugged in. My previous system would not even operate plugged in after about 4 years. My experience is purely anecdotal but has convinced me. I have no doubt that the batteries and related systems (H/W & S/W) are getting better but the difference is nevertheless striking. (Current laptop is 2 1/2 years old.)

Comment: if your previous laptop had a Li-Ion vs LiPo battery, that would explain the degradation (depending on the charging schematics of the motherboard, amount of dendrite buildup, and how many cells dropped).  Most battery packs, whether laptop, power tool, etc. are usually a pack of multiple 18650s wired in series. Due to how volatile lithium batteries are, most have PCBs that act as a safety mechanism to prevent overcharging and a shot circuit between the cathode and anode... should either be tripped, that 18650 will be prevented from charging or discharging, effectively dropping a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a battery at a maximum of around 3.9v avoids stress induced capacity losses. So I charge my battery to 50 percent and take it out. When I want to go out or wander around the house I pop the battery back in. Once every 6 months I give the battery a full cycle. 3 years later its still giving me 2 hours runtime on a huge acer 8930g.

http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

Keeping your battery in a hot laptop fully charged is killing it badly. After 1 year it may lose 30-50 percent capacity.