# How can I set a 80% battery charge limit for a HP Ultrabook?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

I really hope you can answer this simply request.

Nowadays is pretty common to have a new Ultrabook, laptop or notebook for general purposes. A very important feature is to have a healthy battery. We all know that Lithium-batts do a terrific job and are more resistant than ever, but after many years of experience, I've learnt that having a software like "Eco charge, Battery care, Smart charge...etc " is vital feature for long lasting battery good health. Major brands take care of this BUT HP, believe or not. I've just received a new Ultrabook Spectra x360 with windows 8.1, and so far I cannot find any special battery function for this request, even worst nobody can answer in their forum either; I really can't understand this flaw in HP. So, I'd like to know is there any reliable battery software or a way to acccess the battery controller, that can allow me to keep the battery charge to 80% while connected.

I've seen several utilities that keep info about battery and how to optimize but none with the simple function that I need.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi pstrusi, software recommendations are off topic here. Related questions: [Is there an Acer battery management tool that limits the battery charge?](http://superuser.com/questions/698421/is-there-an-acer-battery-management-tool-that-limits-the-battery-charge-should) and [Only allow laptop to charge battery to 95%?](http://superuser.com/q/698421/172747)

Comment: My 2 cents, despite your experience: don't. Why carry 100% of the weight and not use it?

Comment: @pstrusi That's an excellent question.  For the software side of it, [this post](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10441/laptop-battery-charging-control-software-for-windows) over at Software Recommendations SE will hopefully yield answers over time.  For other ways to access the battery controller, this site is probably appropriate, but you may want to adjust your question to that specific question.  Really poor choice by HP to not include that essential functionality out of the box.